# How to assign value of Postgres declared variable with result of SQL query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am writing a postgres function where I have declared a variable called fruit.

```
 $$
    DECLARE
      IN_fruit varchar;
      sql;
    BEGIN
        IN_fruit := EXECUTE 'SELECT fruit FROM fruits WHERE id = 1'
```

How can I get this work in a way that the result returned from this query is stored in the variable IN_fruit, which I can use for later use in my main SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below

```
SELECT INTO IN_fruit  fruit FROM fruits WHERE id = 1
```

Reference here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-SELECT-INTO

Comment: Thanks. It worked. This can also be written as:
SELECT fruit  INTO IN_fruit  FROM fruits WHERE id = 1;

Comment: Yup. Your way is more logical because fruit "will be saved" into IN_fruit :).